# Cauchy distribution and Bartlett test

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, cauchy-distribution

I want to proof that Bartlett test is highly nonrobust in the case of nonnormal data. Is it correct to use Cauchy distribution which has undefined variance to estimate the significance level of this test?

Answer (score 0):

No. If variance is thought of as a feature,  such as a nose is for animals,  then performing a test on noses on a tree isn't useful at all.  You would be better off using something like the hyperbolic secant distribution which also has thick tails or a bounded uniform with different widths.  You could also draw from an asymmetrical distribution.

Another alternative is to cycle through the Pearson family of distributions, restricted to those with a variance and test performance.